# ExtJS 4: Deactivate all tabs in tab panel

Tags: event-handling, extjs4, tabpanel

I would like to deactivate tabs in the tabbar, but I didn't find any method or config property in Sencha docs http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel.

1. When panel is created, first tab is automatically selected (I would like to prevent this)
2. I listen to `beforetabchange` event and prevent it if some data was modified.

What am I waiting for:

1. When tab panel is loaded, any tab shouldn't be activated (choosed)
2. When user starts click on these tabs I should catch that event and handle it by `beforetabchange` handler

Thanks a lot for a help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of tabs will be selected. You can control which one by using activeItem, activeTab properties. Are you trying to create a tab panel without selected item at all?

Comment: Yes, I create tab without `items` config property, so when panel is created it doesn't have any tab, so there is nothing to activate =) But when I dynamicaly load and add tabs into the panel, first tab always appears selected. And I want to prevent this feature.

Comment: why is this chosen as an answer?